# Attempting to find median of a data set with occurrences in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

| Phi | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | 389 |
| 0 | 209 |
| 1 | 405 |
| 2 | 27 |

Phi is the value that I want to calculate the median of with -1 being in the list 389times, 0 209times, etc.

The median function only seems to work if it is in a list and you can do- MEDIAN(A:1,A5) but as this list is hundreds of elements long I don't really want to write it all out.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I've tried an "array formula" from some other forum that seemed similar to my question but they had 3 columns so it didn't seem to translate properly.

In the example list the answer should be a median of 0 as it is the middle value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **Not tested** but maybe [REPT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061) could help

Answer (score 4):

For O365:

```
=LET(
    α, A2:B5,
    MEDIAN(
        REDUCE(
            "",
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),
            LAMBDA(β, γ, VSTACK(β, IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(α, γ, 2)), INDEX(α, γ, 1))))
        )
    )
)
```

*Edit*: `SORT` and `DROP` removed due to being redundant, the former since `MEDIAN` implicitly sorts the range passed, the latter with thanks to *Spectral Instance* (see comments).

Comment: `DROP` is also redundant if you change the first argument to `REDUCE` from `0` to `""`, since `MEDIAN()` ignores text values